# 1yr baby feeling hungry at night but not feeding instead crying

Tags: breastfeeding

My 1yr old baby had fever two days ago.That time he avoided solids and Had only breastfeed milk. But now he refuses to breast feed during night .But crying for long time due to hunger... I just gave little water and tried long time make him sleep. I don't know why he refuses but crying for breastfeeding. I don't what to do.

Comment: Do you know for a fact that he's hungry? If he had a fever recently, he may be crying at night because something hurts. Have you had a talk with your doctor or nurse?

Comment: If he's not eating, he's probably not hungry... if he had a slight fever, he may be teething... there's often a fever with teething.

Comment: Fever is not really a reliable indicator for teething; I'd be more worried about an ear infection. Fussy, reduced intake, crying at night, recent illness... I can't tell you how often this is a presentation for an ear infection, especially if the fever was due to an upper respiratory infection.

Comment: How much of a fever?

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert but it does sound like teething. Refusing to eat and fever are symptoms. I hope you can see these:

[Teething can raise your baby's body temperature, but only slightly. Any fever over 100.4 F/38 C  is a sign that your child is probably sick.](http://www.webmd.com/parenting/baby/can-teething-cause-fever#1)

[Link](https://www.babycenter.com/0_teething-your-babys-first-teeth_11243.bc)

> What are the signs a baby is teething?
>
> Some babies get through teething with no signs at all, but many
>   parents report that their babies do experience discomfort. The most
>   likely signs of teething include:
>
> Irritability or fussiness
>
> Drooling (which can cause a facial rash)
>
> Swollen, sensitive gums
>
> Gnawing or chewing behavior
>
> Refusing to eat
>
> Trouble sleeping
>
> Is it true that teething can cause a fever, diarrhea,
>   or a runny nose?
>
> Some parents say their baby also gets a fever, diarrhea, or a runny
>   nose just before a new tooth arrives, but there's no scientific proof
>   that teething causes these symptoms. The American Academy of
>   Pediatrics says that although a baby's body temperature may rise
>   slightly when teething, a true fever (rectal temperature of 100.4
>   degrees F or higher) and diarrhea aren't normal symptoms. If your
>   child has a fever along with other symptoms such as lack of appetite,
>   vomiting, lethargy, or diarrhea, call her doctor to rule out anything
>   more serious.

If you can't just search for teething and you'll get a similar list of what to expect and what symptoms  the infant/child exhibits.

As anongoodnurse has pointed out, an earache/infection or other illness might also be the cause. See your doctor any time you have a concern or the baby's fever is high lasts beyond a reasonable period.

Comment: I notice you often just add "LINK" to your answers. What if the link rots? It's better to summarize pertinent points in your answers, which are usually helpful. But "LINK" is not an answer.